# Is Clearing ObservableCollection Recommended before Adding Items to it?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

I often need to filter an ObservableCollection that already have items in it. Which approach is better?

```
// Assigning the filtered result directly
FilteredObservableCol = FilteredCollectionCopy.Where(i=> i.Age > 25).ToObservableCollection();
```

Or

```
// Clearing the collection first
FilteredObservableCol.Clear();
FilteredObservableCol = FilteredCollectionCopy.Where(i=> i.Age > 25).ToObservableCollection();
```

Comment: Your snippets won't compile. So neither is better. That said, if you're planning to re-assign the field with new instance --you don't need to clear the old list.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, I missed adding .ToObservableCollection()

Answer (score 2):

You could use `CollectionViewSources` instead of the ObservableCollection to bind to. There you can apply filtering.

```
ICollectionView MyCollection { get; private set; }

public void LoadData()
{
    var myObservable = //... load/create list
    MyCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myObservable);
    MyCollection.Filter = item => ((TypeOfItem)item).Name = "bob";
}
```

Comment: What "myobservable" would be in this case?

Comment: @usefulBee the initial `ObservableCollection`

Comment: A little confusing. I thought MyCollection will completely replace MyObservableCollection. So you are saying that MyObservableCollection will remain bound to the view but the sorting will take place in MyCollection. Is that correct? thx

Comment: @usefulBee I have changed the code a bit to, hopefully, clarify it. You bind to MyCollection, myObservable should not be not visible in XAML

Comment: I keep getting error, "Cannot implicitly convert type ICollectionView to CollectionViewSource"

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It is ICollectionView not ICollectionViewSource.

Comment: The other problem is that "i.Name", "i.Age" etc are not recognized as a valid properties. An example: var myObservable = new List<MySchool>(); MyCollection in this case does not pick the MySchool type, so it won't deliver properties which kind of make sense.

Comment: @usefulBee cast `item` to the type it really is; see, edited code